# Understanding nested if statements in the rock, paper, scissors CodeAcademy Javascript excercise

Tags: javascript

So I've moved on to 6/9 in the CodeAcademy Javascript rock paper scissors excercise and although I've passed it I don't feel 100% confident on nested if statements. I'm starting to log the possible outcomes and this is the code which I passed with:

```
 var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 == choice2) {
        return ("The result is a tie!"); 
    }
    if (choice1 == "rock") {
       if (choice2 == "scissors") {
           return("rock wins"); 
       } else {
          return("paper wins"); }
    }
 }
```

My main query is why? Could you not replace all the nested if statements with just elseif statements instead? I don't feel like I'd know when to use nested if statements.

Comment: FWIW, its called Codecademy, not Codeacademy

Comment: I fixed your indentation (not changing the actual code) which should make things much less confusing

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this code could be written other ways.  It's simply a matter of personal taste.  This would be equivalent:

```
 var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 == choice2) {
        return ("The result is a tie!"); 
    }
    else if (choice1 == "rock" && choice2 == "scissors") {
           return("rock wins"); 
    } else if (choice1 == "rock") { // this assumes choice2 is paper.  you could make it more explicit
          return("paper wins"); 
    }
    // add handling for choice1 being non-rock here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ifs and else...ifs and combining multiple things can make the logic a little bit funny in certain circumstances. I also think that sometimes, nested if statements can help you separate out your logic a little bit easier, making your code more maintanable sometimes (when you need to go back and change some of the logic).

```
var myname = 'josh',
    yourname = 'mary';

if (myname == 'josh') {
    say('hello')

    if(yourname == 'mary') {
        say('mary')
    }

    if(yourname == 'claudia') {
        say('claudia');
    }
} else {

    say(yourname);

}

//'hello mary'
```

```
var myname = 'josh',
    yourname = 'mary';

if (myname == 'josh' && yourname == 'mary') {

    say('hello mary');

} else if (myname == 'josh' && yourname == 'claudia') {

    say('hello claudia');

} else {

    say(yourname);

}

//'hello mary'
```

The number of edits in both examples above would be the same if you need to change all "marys" to "janets"; however, to me, it'd be a little easier to work with the first example for whatever reason.  Perhaps in the example I've given its just personal preference, but I've seen instances where using else..ifs can end up giving you logical outcomes you didn't want to happen.